# Referencing a file from src in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to modify slick's codegen to use my own `SourceCodeGenerator`. So I made my own class extending `SourceCodeGenerator` and put it under `app/utils` where `app` is my source directory. I made an sbt task and referenced this class (`util.MySourceCodeGenerator`) in `build.sbt` but I'm getting the dreaded

```
[error] (run-main-7) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utils.MySourceCodeGenerator
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utils.MySourceCodeGenerator
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:70)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at sbt.Run.getMainMethod(Run.scala:98)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:86)
[error]     at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
```

when running my custom task:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += slick.taskValue // Automatic code generation on build
lazy val slick = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate Tables.scala")

slick := {
  val dir = (scalaSource in Compile) value
  val outputDir = dir
  val jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  val slickDriver = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile"
  val pkg = "models"

  val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile) value
  val s = streams value

  runner.value.run("utils.MySourceCodeGenerator",
    cp.files,
    Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir.getPath, pkg, user, password),
    s.log).failed foreach (sys error _.getMessage)

  val file = outputDir / pkg / "Tables.scala"

  Seq(file)
}
```

Do I need to change my project structure? For reference I'm in Play! framework and I follow this essentially https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Anatomy